# show data and change value if duplicate id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database with tables..

```
A
idA | name
-----------------
1   | A

B
idB | idA | name
-----------------------
2   | 1   | AA
3   | 1   | BB
4   | 1   | CC

C
idC | idA | name
-----------------------
6   | 1   | AAA
7   | 1   | BBB
```

Query is..

```
select
   A.*,
   B.idB, B.name,
   C.idC, C.name
from
   A
join
   B on B.idA=A.idA
join
   C on C.idA=A.idA
```

Then result is..

```
idA  | name    | idB  | name  | idC  | name
----------------------------------------------------
1    | A       | 2    | AA    | 6    | AAA
1    | A       | 2    | AA    | 7    | BBB
1    | A       | 3    | BB    | 6    | AAA
1    | A       | 3    | BB    | 7    | BBB
1    | A       | 4    | CC    | 6    | AAA
1    | A       | 4    | CC    | 7    | BBB
```

> I need result like this..

```
idA  | name    | idB  | name  | idC  | name
----------------------------------------------------
1    | A       | 2    | AA    | 6    | AAA
     |         | 3    | BB    | 7    | BBB
     |         | 4    | CC    |      | 
     |         |      |       |      | 
     |         |      |       |      | 
     |         |      |       |      |
```

Every same or duplicate value/id, it will be change/replace with null or blank value..

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you need a "join" key among the tables.  Actually, the solution (in MySQL) will not use a `join`, but you need to specify the row number for each:

```
select (case when rn = 1 then ida end) as ida,
       (case when rn = 1 then namea end) as namea,
       max(idb) as idb, max(nameb) as nameb,
       max(idc) as idc, max(namec) as namec
from ((select a.idA, a.name as namea, b.id as idb, b.name as nameb,
              NULL as idc, NULL as namec,
              (@rnb := @rnb + 1) as rn
       from a join
            b
            on b.ida = a.id
      ) union all
      (select a.idA, a.name, NULL, NULL,
              c.id as idc, c.name as namec,
              (@rnc := @rnc + 1) as rn
       from a join
            c
            on c.idc = a.id
      )
     ) abc
group by ida, namea, rn;
```

The `union all`/`group by` is essentially implementing a `full outer join` (in this case), which MySQL does not support.

Comment: I've try your query above but it still not help yet. Table C is a static value, example 2 row like above. And table B can changeable values..

Comment: @bideng . . . I have no idea what your comment means.  Your question is about three tables.

Comment: right, there are a three tables. idA from table A is a primary for table B an C. Table B can be a changeable values and table C is a static values..

Answer (score 0):

Table model could be like this..

```
A
idA | name
-----------------
1   | A

B
idB | idA | name
-----------------------
2   | 1   | AA
3   | 1   | BB
5   | 1   | CC
6   | 1   | DD
7   | 1   | EE

C
idC | idA | name
-----------------------
8   | 1   | AAA
9   | 1   | BBB
```

Table B can be a changeable values and table C is a static values..

Answer (score 0):

Then result is..

```
idA  | name    | idB  | name  | idC  | name
----------------------------------------------------
1    | A       | 2    | AA    | 8    | AAA
1    | A       | 2    | AA    | 9    | BBB
1    | A       | 3    | BB    | 8    | AAA
1    | A       | 3    | BB    | 9    | BBB
1    | A       | 5    | CC    | 8    | AAA
1    | A       | 5    | CC    | 9    | BBB
1    | A       | 6    | DD    | 8    | AAA
1    | A       | 6    | DD    | 9    | BBB
1    | A       | 7    | EE    | 8    | AAA
1    | A       | 7    | EE    | 9    | BBB
```

> i need result like this..

```
idA  | name    | idB  | name  | idC  | name
----------------------------------------------------
1    | A       | 2    | AA    | 8    | AAA
     |         | 3    | BB    | 9    | BBB
     |         | 5    | CC    |      | 
     |         | 6    | DD    |      | 
     |         | 7    | EE    |      | 
     |         |      |       |      | 
     |         |      |       |      | 
     |         |      |       |      | 
     |         |      |       |      | 
     |         |      |       |      |
```